# Do registered companies consider experience letters from non-registered companies?

Tags: software-industry, job-change, work-experience, india

I am currently working as a Java Developer in a non-registered Indian company, and wish to move to a registered company soon.

Do registered companies consider a candidate's experience in a non-registered company? In case this is relevant, my current company would soon give me an experience letter stating a work experience of one year.

Comment: @enderland Is this really "seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies"? Or is it a broader question about employment practices in India? I'd be hesitant to close this - especially unilaterally, without 5 close votes

Comment: @Carson63000 I have worked in India for quite a long while, and I can tell that this is most certainly *not* a company-specific regulations question. It seems to fit better in the broader category of employment practices in India. However, I don't know the answer to this question, but would certainly suggest that it be reopened (perhaps with a suitable edit).

Comment: PS: I submitted an edit to this question myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will preface this answer with: I live in America, so my answer may be different than in India.

When I hire a new programmer to work at my company, I glance over their experience, but I generally do not disregard an application based on experience alone. I focus more on what the applicant says they can do and why they would be a good fit for my company. If I believe that the applicant has potential, I will schedule an interview over the phone where I will ask questions that can only be answered if the programmer actually understands what they are doing.

With that said, I think that the experience section of your resume is mainly looked at only in the beginning of the application process and is only used to weed out applicants who have little to no experience.

In short, the answer is yes.

I hope that I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If it is registered or not, you should have relieving letter and experience letter when you leave a company. Insist on it. If possible get some references who can vouch for you.

Adding references is valuable in resume.

Now, to answer your question plainly. If you do not have experience proof and get a job in registered company, then no problem. If a registered company that you want to join has a requirement of previous experience, then you can only show what you have in hand (non-registered company's experience).  Be sure, you never lie. If you prove your skills, then company registration issue becomes nullified.

To avoid all this confusion. Refer [how to check company registration](http://ajeya.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/great-way-to-know-about-companies-a-check-before-your-interview/) before joining. This link can be useful to preliminary information on companies registered in India. Also, avoid interviews and jobs with non-registered companies.